# Nullable dates comparison function - best practice ..find minimum of three dates

Tags: c#, nullable

Scenario: compare to find from given 3 nullable dates

Already working solution: compare them using normal ternary operator (?) but the code is coming out bit too long for 3 dates and if there is fourth date added later in future, then code will suck. It looks ugly, but works.

```
(firstdate == null
    ? ((seconddate == null
        ? (thirddate == null ? null : thirddate)
        : (thirddate == null ? seconddate : ((seconddate < thirddate) ? seconddate : thirddate))) == null
        ? null
        : (seconddate == null
            ? (thirddate == null ? null : thirddate)
            : (thirddate == null ? seconddate : ((seconddate < thirddate) ? seconddate : thirddate))))
    : ((seconddate == null
        ? (thirddate == null ? null : thirddate)
        : (thirddate == null ? seconddate : ((seconddate < thirddate) ? seconddate : thirddate))) == null
        ? firstdate
        : ((firstdate < result)
            ? firstdate
            : (seconddate == null
                ? (thirddate == null ? null : thirddate)
                : (thirddate == null ? seconddate : ((seconddate < thirddate) ? seconddate : thirddate))))))
```

Has anyone solved this before and works for nullable dates? Can someone share best practice with examples?

Thank you.

Comment: My brain just melted. Please attempt to format that?  We're here to help you, make it easy on us. :)

Comment: `thirddate == null ? null : thirddate` is effectively `thirddate`... and the whole thing can be written in 6 lines.

Comment: ...Can you instead tell us what you're trying to do? Reading that code is impossible. If you tell us your expected inputs/outputs, I'm sure it can be written cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

```
ret = firstdate;
if (ret == null || (seconddate != null && seconddate < ret))
    ret = seconddate;
if (ret == null || (thirddate != null && thirddate < ret))
    ret = thirddate;
return ret;
```

Comment: Apologies. I was trying to find Minimum of three values for these nullable dates..

Comment: Thank you, pushing the limit, can we do it in one expression rather than two

Comment: only if you want to make a mess (see other answer).  This way is easier to read and maintian,  and easily extends to more dates

Answer (score 0):

Resharper helped *a lot* when fixing up the code / removing redundancies.

```
return (firstdate == null
    ? ((seconddate == null
        ? (thirddate)
        : (thirddate == null ? seconddate : ((seconddate < thirddate) ? seconddate : thirddate))))
    : ((seconddate == null
        ? (thirddate)
        : (thirddate == null ? seconddate : ((seconddate < thirddate) ? seconddate : thirddate))) == null
        ? firstdate
        : ((firstdate < result)
            ? firstdate
            : (seconddate == null
                ? (thirddate)
                : (thirddate == null ? seconddate : ((seconddate < thirddate) ? seconddate : thirddate))))));
```

So in an attempt to figure out what the code does:

1. If firstdate is null, return the smallest of second & thirddate, or null if both are null
2. If firstdate is *not* null, return firstdate if firstdate < result, otherwise return the smallest of second & thirddate, or null if both are null.

So...

```
if (firstDate.HasValue && firstDate.Value < result)
    return firstDate;

var otherDates = new[] { seconddate, thirddate };
return otherDates.Min();
```

Comment: I am sorry to confuse with my sloppy way of putting question and code. I was just trying to get MIN of 3 given nullable dates.

Comment: @Jonathan Then, the simplest, and most easy-to-understand is `new[] { firstdate, seconddate, thirddate }.Min();`. If they are all null, it returns null, otherwise it returns the lowest date.

Answer (score -1):

I learned this the hard way.  Never code multiway comparisons by hand unless you're desperate for the absolute last bit of efficiency.  It's not worth it.

And if extension of the number of possible values is an issue, then hand-writing inline comparisons is a bad answer in that beyond about four the code is spaghetti.

If you had an arbitrary array of values, and you wanted the smallest, you'd knock up a routine that found it in no time.  Yet because it's a fixed set, there is a tendency to try to write a specific solution that is more effort.

Create an array of the dates.

Then pick the minimum value.

The fact that they are nullable isn't relevant and doesn't materially complicate the issue - you just use GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue) on all comparisons so that a real date is always less than a null.

Two quick solutions:

```
/* 1. Sort the list and take the first */

DateTime?[] dates = {dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4};

dates.Sort (New NullableDateTimeComparer);
return dates(0);

/* Then later */    

public class NullableDateTimeComparer : IComparer<DateTime>
{
  public new int IComparer(DateTime x, DateTime y)
  {
    return DateTime.Compare(x.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue), .GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue);
  }
}

/* 2. Write a custom function that takes the minimum if you must: */

DateTime?[] dates = {dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4};
return MinDate(dates);

/* Then Later */

static public DateTime? MinDate(DateTime?[] dates)
{
  DateTime? min;
  for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; ++i)
    if (dates[i].GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue) < min.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue))
      min = dates[i];
  return min;
}
```

You never have to worry about whether or not you'll remember how you did it, you'll never have to even think about how to extend it for a larger use case, and the loss of efficiency is too small to worry about except in the most exceptional cases.